# Persist HTML control values after submission in ASPX

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, retain

I have HTML elements (input, select specifically) in a div tag of an aspx from. I do some calculations on them using Jquery. My submit button performs validation using an onclientclick and if that returns true, then server side actions take place (onclick event of submit button).
 However, as soon as I submit, the HTML elements loose their value and become blank. I want to retain those values after the submission so that the users can see what they had typed before they submitted. 
Some people ma suggest `<asp:UpdatePanel>`. But, I don't want to use .NET AJAX.
Can this be done with Jquery/Javascript?

Following is the sample of HTML inside the aspx page.

```
<input id="txtLength10"  onchange="cc(10);" type="text" class="numeric"  maxlength="25"    />

<select id="ddClass10"><option value="10">Select Class</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no luck on the above question. Finally, I took all the values of the controls that I needed in aspx hiddenfield and then used a checked if there was a value present on that hiddenfield on a onload event.

`$(document).ready(function() {

 if ($('#<%=hdfFILLER.ClientID %>').val() != "") {
                //use regex to break this string and fill all the html controls
            }});`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `runat="server"` attribute for both the form elements.

This way both will be treated as [html server controls](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refhtmlcontrols.asp) and the selected/entered values will be persisted across postbacks.

```
<input id="txtLength10" runat="server" onchange="cc(10);" type="text" class="numeric"  maxlength="25"   />
<select id="ddClass10" runat="server"><option value="10">Select Class</option></select>
```

Comment: I cant make them runat server because then I have to refer them using ClientID in jquery calculations. The problem is i do something like:

`//paddedcounter is a counter from 1 to 10 (01 to 10)
$('#ddClass' + paddedcounter + ' option:selected').val(Commodity_Class)`

in case of using clientID I get 'too many literals error'

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the ClientID will be the same as the id specified in the markup (when the html controls are within an aspx page).

Comment: `$('#<%= ddClass'+paddedcounter+'.ClientID %>').val()` gives error too many literals

Comment: why don't you select the id with a jquery wildcard selector? $("[id^=ddClass]")

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed: Thats a nice idea. But I am assigning values like p
pack1 = L1.val()*B1.val()*H1.val(); 
pack2 = L2.val()*B2.val()*H2.val();
Can this be done? Also will it detect server side elements. Can you
 write a sample code snippet?

Comment: @jdavies:Yes I am using a Master PAge?

Comment: Try adding the attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the html elements. This will tell ASP.NET to use the static id specified in the markp. That way you can use `$('#ddClass' + paddedcounter + ' option:selected').val(Commodity_Class)`.

Comment: @jdavies: you mean <asp:Content Id="" ClientIDMode="Static" />
I tried that and made the elements run at server...not getting any values

Comment: No, I mean `<input id="txtLength10" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ...` and `<select id="ddClass10" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ...`. Because the id's of the html elements will be static (as entered in the markup), this will enable you to  use JQuery without requesting the ClientID.

Comment: Could you explain why it doesn't work? Setting the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` should enable you to use the id of the element as specified in the markup, exactly the same as you would if the html control was not marked as a server control (`runat="server`).

Comment: @jdaives: I appreciate your quick responses and possibilities but when I do the foll js, I get an undefined value, even when I input the values.
`$('#txtLength' + paddedcounter + ' option:selected').val()`
Is there a place where you can show me that this works, even a snapshot would work? An article or blog would do too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function of jQuery to [communicate with the server](http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-08-07/asp_net-mvc_3-jquery-ajax-submit-ajax-form-supporting-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-and-server-side-validation). This omits using Microsoft's Ajax implementation while not using any post back, thus keeping the DOM you build on the client intact.

Comment: How can I do that. 
My submit button looks something like this
`<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" 
            OnClick="serversidefunction" OnClientClick="return Validate();clientsidefunction" />`

Answer (score 0):

I have a blog post I did a couple weeks ago on "Asp.Net – Persisting Data between Pages via the Session object" You could use the code I've posted there and reaload your controls with the persisted data between postbacks. It's not a client side option but if you end up going the server side route this could help.

http://blogbydylan.com/blog/2011/10/asp-net-persisting-data-between-pages-via-the-session-object/